# SQL count distinct row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

[image]

with each row representing a review given by a user. I want to get the users by the number of distinct cities they wrote reviews in. For example:

cities, users

1,1012388

2,221758

which means that 1012388 users wrote reviews for businesses in one city only.

I tried:

```
select count(distinct(city)) as city, count(user_id) 
from table1
group by user_id 
order by count(user_id) desc
```

Comment: Please delete that screen capture and instead include your data as a text table.  Then, include sample output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to find the number of distinct city reviews that each user wrote:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(DISTINCT city) AS num_reviews
FROM table1
GROUP BY user_id
```

Then you can group that data by number of reviews:

```
SELECT num_reviews, COUNT(user_id) AS num_users
FROM (SELECT user_id, COUNT(DISTINCT city) AS num_reviews
      FROM table1
      GROUP BY user_id) r
GROUP BY num_reviews
ORDER BY num_users DESC
```

Comment: Why do I need the ```GROUP BY num_reviews```?

Comment: @iilla because you are trying to count the number of users who gave that many reviews.

Comment: Thanks, and what is the ```r```in the second last line?Is it a typo?

Comment: @iilla no, every derived table must have an alias, and that is what the `r` is for. If you remove it, you will get an `every derived table must have an alias` error.

Comment: Got it! And you need to add```ORDER BY COUNT(user_id) DESC```in the end to get the exact result.

Comment: @iilla yes, or just `ORDER BY num_users DESC` since you can refer to column aliases in order by clauses